# Column as a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to have a 3rd column which will sum all points per 1st column (word) but that it will sum the points from all words that are like the '%word%' of each line, for example the word 'chef' will have the points of 'chef' and 'kitchen chef' and etc.

```
SELECT word, SUM(points) as points  
  FROM table
group by word
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server? They are 2 very different RDBMS.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? Do you have to do this as a sub query as coursework?

Comment: It's sql server and I'm trying to get something like this, of course it doesn't work
 SELECT word ,sum(points) as points,
sum(points where word like '%'+word+'%')
FROM Table 
group by word

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong with the title but it seemed to me that there has to be a sub query to have the result

Comment: Aside: This has the classic feature of finding the words "so", "us" and "chef" in "sous-chef" because you aren't parsing words out of the string, just matching groups of letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this. Joining on a LIKE is not very performant however.

```
;WITH Words AS(
    SELECT word ,sum(points) as points, 
    FROM table group by word
)

SELECT
    W.word,
    W.points,
    LikeWordPoints = W.points + ISNULL(SUM(LikeWord.points),0)
FROM
    Words W
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Words LikeWord ON LikeWord.word LIKE '%'+W.word+'%' AND LikeWord.word <> W.word
GROUP BY
    W.word,
    W.points
```

Comment: You are assuming the table works as a dictionary and cant have repeated words. I believe is a fair assumption but if that isnt the case you will miss some points.

Comment: I read it as each word is summed and added to points of other similar words. If repeated words hold the same weight then then a query similar to above will work. If each match within a word is desired then this is not the correct query :/

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I'd probably use a `correlated subquery` for this:

```
select distinct w.word, 
      (select sum(points) from words w2 where w2.word like '%' + w.word + '%') as points
from words w
```

- [Online Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67c815/1)

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subquery within a select can reduce performance. I would recommend using join or cross apply

```
select distinct w.word, C.SumOfPoints as sumofpoints
from words w
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(points) AS SumOfPoints from words w2 WHERE w2.word like '%' + 
w.word + '%') C
```

Comment: Nagashree Hs
Thanks, will use it